# Exporting feature class into multiple feature classes based on field values using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, select-by-attribute, split-by-attribute

I have a feature class with over 2,000 features, and I need to make them all individual feature classes based on a field.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You may use the Split By Attributes tool:

> Splits an input dataset by unique attributes

There are versions available for:

- [ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/split-by-attributes.htm) (available at all license levels)
- [ArcGIS Desktop 10.8](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm) (available at all license levels)
- [USGS versions (Split By Attribute Tool)](https://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html)

Answer (score 24):

You can achieve this with a very simple model if you have ArcGIS 10.0 or higher.

Create a model with Feature Iterator where the group by field is the attribute you wish to select by then send the output to the copy features tool using inline substitution to ensure a unique file name. The model is shown below:

[image: Model for extracting by attribute]

Answer (score 17):

I do not have access to ArcMap 10, only 9.3, but I expect that it won't be very different from this.

You can create a simple script in Python, that checks your attribute field for different values, and then, for each of them runs a SELECT operation to your original Shapefile.

If you are not familiar with python scripting, all you need to do is open you IDLE (the python GUI) create a new file, and copy the code below. After adapting the code for your my_shapefile, outputdir and my_attribute it should work.

```python
# Script created to separate one shapefile in multiple ones by one specific
# attribute

# Example for a Inputfile called "my_shapefile" and a field called "my_attribute"
import arcgisscripting

# Starts Geoprocessing
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.OverWriteOutput = 1

#Set Input Output variables
inputFile = u"C:\\GISTemp\\My_Shapefile.shp" #<-- CHANGE
outDir = u"C:\\GISTemp\\" #<-- CHANGE

# Reads My_shapefile for different values in the attribute
rows = gp.searchcursor(inputFile)
row = rows.next()
attribute_types = set([])

while row:
    attribute_types.add(row.my_attribute) #<-- CHANGE my_attribute to the name of your attribute
    row = rows.next()

# Output a Shapefile for each different attribute
for each_attribute in attribute_types:
    outSHP = outDir + each_attribute + u".shp"
    print outSHP
    gp.Select_analysis (inputFile, outSHP, "\"my_attribute\" = '" + each_attribute + "'") #<-- CHANGE my_attribute to the name of your attribute

del rows, row, attribute_types, gp

#END
```

Answer (score 9):

I used [@AlexandreNeto's script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/44435/115) and **updated it for ArcGIS 10.x** users. Mainly you now have to import "arcpy" instead of "arcgisscripting":

```py
# Script created to separate one shapefile in multiple ones by one specific
# attribute

# Example for a Inputfile called "my_shapefile" and a field called "my_attribute"
import arcpy

#Set Input Output variables
inputFile = u"D:\DXF-Export\my_shapefile.shp" #<-- CHANGE
outDir = u"D:\DXF-Export\\" #<-- CHANGE

# Reads My_shapefile for different values in the attribute
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(inputFile)
row = rows.next()
attribute_types = set([])

while row:
    attribute_types.add(row.my_attribute) #<-- CHANGE my_attribute to the name of your attribute
    row = rows.next()

# Output a Shapefile for each different attribute
for each_attribute in attribute_types:
    outSHP = outDir + each_attribute + u".shp"
    print outSHP
    arcpy.Select_analysis (inputFile, outSHP, "\"my_attribute\" = '" + each_attribute + "'")     #<-- CHANGE my_attribute to the name of your attribute

del rows, row, attribute_types

#END
```

Answer (score 7):

This is an even easier way to do this... and it outputs into a GDB.

http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html

download the tool from USGS, took me 3 minutes to do what i had been trying for 1 hour.

Answer (score 6):

I know you can use an iterator in ModelBuilder, but if you prefer to use python here is something I came up with. Add the script to a toolbox with the parameters in order as Input shpfile, fields(multivalue,obtained from input), and workspace. This script will split the shapefile into multiple shapefiles based on the fields you select, and output them into a folder of your choice.

```py
import arcpy, re

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

Input = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)  
Flds = "%s" % (arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)) 
OutWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) 


myre = re.compile(";")
FldsSplit = myre.split(Flds)

sort = "%s A" % (FldsSplit[0])
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(Input, "", "", Flds, sort)

for row in rows:
    var = []
    for r in range(len(FldsSplit)):
        var.append(row.getValue(FldsSplit[r]))
    Query = ''
    Name = ''
    for x in range(len(var)):
        if x == 0:
            fildz = FldsSplit[x]
            Name = var[x] + "_"
            Query += (""" "%s" = '%s'""" % (fildz, var[x]))
        if x > 0:
            fildz = FldsSplit[x]
            Name += var[x] + "_"
            Query += (""" AND "%s" = '%s' """ % (fildz, var[x]))
    OutputShp = OutWorkspace + r"\%s.shp" % (Name)
    arcpy.Select_analysis(Input, OutputShp, Query)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have eventually got it working with SearchCursor and Select_analysis

```
arcpy.env.workspace = strInPath
# create a set to hold the attributes
attributes=set([])
# ---- create a list of feature classes in the current workspace ----
listOfFeatures = arcpy.SearchCursor(strInPath,"","",strFieldName,"")
for row in listOfFeatures:
    attributes.add(row.getValue(strFieldName))
    count=1
try:
    for row in attributes:
        stroOutputClass = strBaseName + "_" +str(count)# (str(row.getValue(strFieldName))).replace('/','_')
        strOutputFeatureClass = os.path.join(strOutGDBPath, stroOutputClass)
        arcpy.Select_analysis(strInPath,strOutputFeatureClass,strQueryExp)#"["+strFieldName+"]"+"='"+row+"'")
        count=count+1
    del attributes
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage('Error found')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Search Cursor to loop through individual features in a feature class and write just the geometries to unique feature classes.  In this example, I use a feature class of the USA and export the states to new shapefiles:

```py
import arcpy

# This is a path to an ESRI FC of the USA
states = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb\USA\states'
out_path = r'C:\temp'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(states, ["STATE_NAME", "SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        out_name = str(row[0]) # Define the output shapefile name (e.g. "Hawaii")
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(row[1], out_path, out_name)
```

Comment: I think the downside of this answer is that you do not carry through the attributes.  I prefer an answer more like http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152165/115 which will.

Comment: Good point @PolyGeo, however, the upside is that this can be wrapped into other workflows that also require `cursor` operations.

Comment: ... but so could using Select_analysis in place of FeatureClassToFeatureClass - it's only one line of code that would change.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [geometry token](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001t000000) (SHAPE@) within [Copy Features (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000) to export each feature.

```
import arcpy, os

shp = r'C:\temp\yourSHP.shp'
outws = r'C:\temp'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["OBJECTID","SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        outfc = os.path.join(outws, "fc" + str(row[0]))
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(row[1], outfc)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the Iterate Feature Selection tools in ModelBuilder, but exporting just that as Python code indicate that they can be called using arcpy.

```
    # Created on: 2015-05-19 15:26:10.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Load required toolboxes
arcpy.ImportToolbox("Model Functions")


# Local variables:
Selected_Features = ""
Value = "1"

# Process: Iterate Feature Selection
arcpy.IterateFeatureSelection_mb("", "", "false")
```

Answer (score 2):

In Arcpy, Cursors honor layer/TableView selections. According to [Getting list of selected features in ArcGIS for Desktop using Python code?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44733), you can simply iterate feature selections.

However if you want to make a selection using arcpy, use [SelectLayerByAttribute_management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/0017/001700000071000000.htm) tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ModelBuilder for this type of operation. In this example, I created a separate variable "out_workspace" that is used to define the output path in Copy Features:

`%out_workspace%\fc_%Value%.shp`

[image]