# generate massive shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table

I have a shapefile with 1475 records, and I want to generate a shapefile for each record.

What can I do to generate them avoiding selecting and exporting each record to do that?

Comment: That isn't a massive number of records! Do you have command line or python access to gdal? Can you show the schema (data types / fields) for your shapefile data?

Comment: I understand some of code, but still I don't know python. You can have to the shapefile itself. The URL is this: http://www.dtpm.cl/index.php/2013-04-24-14-10-40/2013-04-26-17-44-02 <br/> The name of the shapefile is **Consolidado de Archivos Geográficos de Rutas -Shape - (12/04/14)**

Comment: consider http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/how-to-split-a-shapefile-into-separate-files-for-each-feature

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume you have access to Excel and this is a one-off and you don't want to (or are unwilling to) write a program.

Open the .dbf file in excel - yes, it's an Excel type **just don't save it**. What you want is just the FID field, but that's not there is it! You will notice that the records are arranged sequentially and consecutively (1-n with no breaks). Start a new worksheet and close the dbf, insert a series for the number of records (1-1475).

Insert a column before the series in the worksheet and copy this into it:

ogr2ogr -where FID=

Which is the [OGR2OGR command](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html). In this example I'm using a query filter which can adapt to any unique attribute or group of features. The other option is -fid .

in the column after the FID put your output shapefile and use your imagination for the output shape file, in this example I have used `="d:\OutPath\Out" & B1 & ".shp"`. The input shape file goes last.

[image: FIRST ROW]

fill the table by selecting the cells A, C & D for all the rows and use Ctrl + D to fill down. The fomula will change each output file:

[image: FILLED ROWS]

Now save as CSV, ignore the warnings, open with Notepad and you will get:

```
ogr2ogr -where FID=,1,d:\OutPath\Out1.shp,d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where FID=,2,d:\OutPath\Out2.shp,d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where FID=,3,d:\OutPath\Out3.shp,d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where FID=,4,d:\OutPath\Out4.shp,d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where FID=,5,d:\OutPath\Out5.shp,d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where FID=,6,d:\OutPath\Out6.shp,d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where FID=,7,d:\OutPath\Out7.shp,d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where FID=,8,d:\OutPath\Out8.shp,d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where FID=,9,d:\OutPath\Out9.shp,d:\some_path\InShape.shp
```

Do a find & replace `FID=,` with `FID=`, then `,` with space and you will get this:

```
ogr2ogr -where  FID=1 d:\OutPath\Out1.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where  FID=2 d:\OutPath\Out2.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where  FID=3 d:\OutPath\Out3.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where  FID=4 d:\OutPath\Out4.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where  FID=5 d:\OutPath\Out5.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where  FID=6 d:\OutPath\Out6.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where  FID=7 d:\OutPath\Out7.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where  FID=8 d:\OutPath\Out8.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -where  FID=9 d:\OutPath\Out9.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
```

Which is batch commands! Save the file with the extension .bat and then double click to run.

The other way of exporting using -FID looks like this:

```
ogr2ogr -FID 1 d:\OutPath\Out1.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -FID 2 d:\OutPath\Out2.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -FID 3 d:\OutPath\Out3.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -FID 4 d:\OutPath\Out4.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -FID 5 d:\OutPath\Out5.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -FID 6 d:\OutPath\Out6.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -FID 7 d:\OutPath\Out7.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -FID 8 d:\OutPath\Out8.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
ogr2ogr -FID 9 d:\OutPath\Out9.shp d:\some_path\InShape.shp
```

**traps** Paths with spaces must be enclosed in "", so `D:\project data\FromShape.shp` becomes `"d:\project data\FromShape.shp"`. 
OGR2OGR comes with QGIS but you might need to do some changes to get it to work. If the computer can't find the program insert the line `set path=C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\bin;%path%` in the top of the batch file... obviously substitute your own path to QGIS\bin folder, this one is for Dufour.

Comment: Thank you, It run, but it didn't show me any result. But, I found another way to do it. On the processing toolbox of QGIS, there is a script called Split vector layer by attribute. That script works very well.

Comment: That's a shame. It worked for me; I did notice that if there is something wrong with the *-where* syntax it ran without error messages but created no output. It is distinctly possible that the *split vector layer by attribute* is merely a GUI for this process or very similar.