# Export each feature to a new geojson individually

Tags: qgis, geojson, export

I have a shp file in qgis. I would like to export that shp file into geojson. I have seen the save as option. But, my point is to create individual files for each individual shape in the gis project. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate of this question. I think that OP wants to generate seperate layer with each one feature of existing layer. Not splitting by other layer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **Save seleted features** from processing toolbox. Select layer and check **iterate** button, which runs algorithm (in our case - save) separately on each feature. When choosing output file, select *Files of type* **GeoJSON**. By default, output layers will be numbered.
[image]

Comment: You can find it in menu *Processing --> Toolbox* (or `CTRL + ALT + T`), or like activating other panel/toolbar rightclick somwhere on panel/toolbar and check what you want to appear. If you don't see *Processing* in the menu, probably its deactivated in plugin manager (*Plugins --> Manage and Install Plugins...*)

Comment: Thank you! It's really helpful. One last thing: can we change the way of output naming? E.g. a value from table of attributes.

Comment: I thought about this :) I don't have experiences with this, but I think it is interesting task, so if its not anwsered before, don't hesitate start new question about this. I wrote a small python script some time ago, but its handling only names in Layer panel after iterations not the files. So maybe some experienced have already solution on this task.

Comment: I tried this method, and it gave this error message, "There are no selected features in the input layer." Fortunately there is another method that worked for me. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/splitting-shapefile-into-separate-files-for-each-feature-using-qgis-gdal-saga

Comment: You can also use 'split vector Layer' in the vector toolbar (native:splitvectorlayer), if you want to specify a layer name using a dynamic value.