# How to generate a single kml file for each feature in a kml file?

Tags: kml, features, xml

I have a kml file containing features that I would like to parse out into separate kml files for each feature/header.

I'm hoping there is an easy way to do this using geojson.io or QGIS.

**How can I generate separate kml files for each feature/header in a single kml file?**

Comment: Could you put some test data available? KML file with 2 features is a minimum.

Comment: This might work: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/splitting-shapefile-into-separate-files-for-each-feature-using-qgis-gdal-saga