# Layer view control

Tags: qgis

I would like to know if you can put the option to select a layer that is within a group of layers.
Example: I have a group called Cities (It contains 10 cities) and I want to have the option of going to make visible the cities of interest and not all at once.

Isso é possível fazer pelo QGIS2WEB?

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like to turn on a single layer (city) at a time?

Answer (score 1):

While showing a group will by default display all of its layers, you can turn them on/off individually by (un)checking the box beside them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have them as different layers.

You can do this using the split vector layer tool:

[Splitting shapefile into separate files for each feature using QGIS/GDAL/SAGA?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/splitting-shapefile-into-separate-files-for-each-feature-using-qgis-gdal-saga)