# Results from split vector layer not showing

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to split a vector layer into multiple polygons (there'll be about 200 or 300, when it works), but nothing is showing up once I've run the vector split tool, neither on the layers side of the window, or in the processing results on the other side. Processing history says it's run. This is what I've done, several times:

[image: Split vector not showing results]

I'm using QGIS Desktop 3.8.1 and the CSR is EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to create a folder and set it as destination for the tool ? In your screenshot you left it as [save to temporary folder], that may be the problem.

Comment: Take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/splitting-shapefile-into-separate-files-for-each-feature-using-qgis-gdal-saga. The comment by AndreJ on the top answer notes this tool doesn't automatically add new layers to your project.

Comment: J.R that worked  - thank you very much! I didn't understand I had to do that...