# How to split a single OSM layer of a Key (eg highway) containing multiple Values into separate layers of the values in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am using Quick OSM in QGIS 3.12.3-București. When I *'Run query'* for a specific geocodeArea, eg London, and I specify the *'Key'*, eg Highway, but I leave the *'Value'* blank; (img 1). The result is one layer in QGIS with **all** of the *Values* of highway on it; (img 2) (well its 3 layers - Nodes, lines and hatches. but for the sake of this question, let's just say it's one layer).

What I would like to achieve is to have all of the *Values* for the *Key* (eg highway) to be on **individual layers** in QGIS. So I can avoid having to 'run query' for each and every *value* of 'highway'. As this is a laborious process and there must be a faster way.

I have looked into the *'Overpass query'* method, but iv'e only found it gives me the same result of everything in one layer.

Is there a piece of code I can add into the *Overpass query* to tell it to load the values on to separate layers? Or is there a way to split the layer after it has been loaded, into separate layers of the *Values* of the *Key*?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/splitting-shapefile-into-separate-files-for-each-feature-using-qgis-gdal-saga) provides the answer, which is to use "Split Vector Layer" from the processing toolbox. Beware that the result is NOT added to the map - each new layer is saved as a geopkg in the directory you specify (or a temp directory you'll have to go hunting for.)