# Disabling some topology rules temporarily to speed up checking other rules using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, topology, arcgis-10.6

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

I have a topology with a large number of rules and many feature classes.  I need to check only certain rules and feature classes and wondering the best way to do this without having to validate the whole topology across all the rules?

I know I can search for only certain rules in the error inspector window, but I want to filter the process even before that, by telling the topology to ignore some rules until i turn them back on.

Is that possible?  Is there a better way to approach doing this when I have a large cadaster with many records and want to just check it against specific situations?

Comment: Make a copy of your database, remove the rules you don't want from your topology, validate then use Export Topology Errors https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000015w000000 to create geometries that show where the errors will be, visit the geometries https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152536/using-arcgis-desktop-to-zoom-to-next-selected-feature/152668#152668 and fix in the original. You can have multiple copies of the database validating only one rule to speed things up (in multiple Catalog windows) then merge the exported geometries when validation is done.

Comment: I had considered this but was hoping that was not the solution to avoid such a process.  There are a number of single rule permutations I want to be able to run quickly, so I would be copying/weeding the rules/validating/exporting/importing/fixing, and then repeating for other rules and layers.  So seems a bit tedious when needing to do it many times in different rule/data permutations, I am hoping for something a bit more graceful, but perhaps this is the only approach.

Comment: It's the only approach I know; even in ArcObjects you can't suppress a rule or validate a single rule. I know it's tedious but if you need to do this a lot you can create a model to copy the database multiple times and trim the rules. I would also be interested if anyone has a different approach.

Comment: Probably for most rules you could write some python to do the validation outside of the topology. You could use parallel processing to do it faster.. however this is much more work than just copying the data and simplifying the topology.