# creating many Shapefiles from from a single multi-polygonal shapefile using ArGIS tools

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, splitting

I have a country shapefile with many districts polygons which are administrative boundaries, I want to have a shapefile for each of the district, which tool in ArcGIS can I use to accomplish this

Comment: I think you are looking for "Split By Attribute" functionality: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/9998/115

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Split (Analysis) Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000006000000).  Use your districts as the Split Features.

(For QGIS users, we have a similar tool in Vector->Data Management->Split Vector Layer)

Comment: The split by attribute tool has worked very well for my case. Thank you