# Splitting shapefile into features and keeping attributes using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I want to split a shapefile so each feature becomes its own shapefile. The below works:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(catch10, ["FID", "SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
      out_name = "Sup_" + str(row1[0]) # 
      arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(row1[1],outSup, out_name, **field_mapping=**)
```

But the attributes don't come with it. It gives back a shapefile with FID (0), Shape, ID (0). I have tried different entries under field mapping -- long strings copied from results and shorter {"Name" etc) -- but nothing has changed it. I'm missing something

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/exporting-feature-class-into-multiple-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-usin

Comment: The split by attribute tool seems perfect for the job, but what happened to it? The code above is based on aaron's answer to that question (further down). This doesn't bring over my attributes

Comment: Did you run this tool?  http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html

Comment: Try including all fields in your arcpy.da.SearchCursor... you're limiting it to ["FID", "SHAPE@"] according to http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000 specify '*' to have all fields.

Comment: I think this is the best answer there (http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152165/115) - it is a similar coding pattern to the one I teach in the [eLearning video tutorial](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/124232/115) that I mention in my answer there.

Comment: @klewis -- can one use that tool (an add-in on the toolbar) with arcpy? how do you call it?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson -- I tried a few versions of * ( should be ["*"] or "*", right?) but the tool throws an error. I also tried ["Name"] but the tuple index is out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The row object can't be used in the manner that you're attempting:

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(row1[1],outSup...
```

Because it's a row and not a feature class, to split your feature class to a single feature per output:

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(catch10)
OID_Field = desc.OIDFieldName # the name of the OID field, could be OID, OBJECTID, FID or other

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(catch10,'*') as SCur: # really all you need here is arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InData,[OID_Field])
    for row in SCur:
        print 'OID {0}'.format(row[0])
        out_name = "Sup_{0}".format(row[0])
        arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(catch10,outSup,out_name,'{0} = {1}'.format(OID_Field,row[0]))
```

It is important to describe the data first and obtain the OID field name, this saves maintaining a script for shapefiles and a different one for geodatabases, then start your cursor with only the OID field, as that's all that's needed to supply the whereclause `OIDFieldName = This_row_OID`, then specify the source data in [FeatureClassToFeatureClass](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000020000000), note that the [Select tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000005000000) also could be implemented here (different to the [other select tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000v6000000) so make sure you're using the right one).