# Arcpy -- TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable -- I believe it is a feature class error but not sure how to solve

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, typeerror

I'm somewhat new to Python and am working on automating some of the daily processes we do at my company. In this code example, I'm trying to automate pulling in data from a CSV file, creating buffers and drive time around that data, and then appending spatial data to those created trade areas.

I'm currently have an error message that says "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". I've looked through some of the other questions related to that topic here, but none of them answer my issue; it's not a workspace concern.

The error is occurring in line 51, the for fcBuffer in featureClasses loop. I understand that the error is happening because it's saying there are no feature classes. The only thing I can think of is that the MakeXYEventLayer function only creates a layer and not a feature class.

If that is the case, how do I convert those layers into feature classes?

Another potential concern.

Do I need to put in code to skip the header row of the table during the for loop with the MakeXYEventLayer function?

Or does it run through that table skipping the header row already because there is no XY data there?

Here is my code:

```
#import arcpy and arcview library; overwrite any previous output
import arcpy
import arcview
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#set workspace to GetParameter field
myWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = myWorkspace
print arcpy.env.workspace

#acquire extensions for Business Analyst and Network Analyst for use
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Business")
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

#in order to use its tools, add Business Analyst toolbox to script
arcpy.AddToolbox("C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\Business Analyst\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Business Analyst Tools.tbx")

#create GetParameter for input csv table that has store location and lat/long
inputTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#set variables for lat/long table
location = "Location"
xCoord = "Long"
yCoord = "Lat"

#set the spatial reference; 4269 is code for GCS_North_American_1983
spatialRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(4269)

#use for loop to create XY feature class for each location in csv table
for row in inputTable:
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(inputTable, xCoord, yCoord, "Location_{0}".format(location), spatialRef)

#create variable of feature classes created by previous MakeXYLayer function (only point files)
featureClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("", "Point")
print featureClasses

#for each XY point layer created, run a 0.5, 1, and 3 mile buffer
for fcBuffer in featureClasses:
    arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(featureClasses, "Buffer_{0}".format(fcBuffer), [0.5, 1, 3], "Miles")

#for ecah XY point layer created, run a 2.5, 5, and 10 minute drive time trade area
for fcDriveTime in featureClasses:
    arcpy.DriveTime_ba(featureClasses, location, "All", "2.5,5,10", "Minutes", "DriveTime_{0}".format(fcDriveTime))

#Create variable of feature classes created by previous rings and drive time functions
BufferClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Buffer")
DriveTimeClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("DriveTime")

#Create variables for spatial overlay function
InputLayer = "C:\ArcGIS\Business Analyst\US_2015\Data\Demographic Data\esri_bg.bds"
DemogFields = "INDMGMT_CY; A25I25_CY; A35I150_CY; A45I75_CY; MEDIA55_CY; \
                MEDDIA35CY; A15NW250CY; AVGNWA65CY; MEDVAL_CY; POPGRWCYFY; \
                N14_EMP; N17_BUS; N18_BUS; N34_EMP"

#Run spatial overlay to append data to buffers and drive time
for BufferAppend in BufferClasses:
    arcpy.SpatialOverlay_ba(InputLayer, BufferClasses, DemogFields, "BufferAppend_{0}".format(BufferAppend))

for DriveTimeAppend in DriveTimeClasses:
    arcpy.SpatialOverlay_ba(InputLayer, DriveTimeClasses, DemogFields, "DriveTimeAppend_{0}".format(DriveTimeAppend))

#Create variable of feature classes created by spatial overlay functions
BufferAppendClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("BufferAppend")
DriveTimeAppendClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("DriveTimeAppend")

#Create function for exporting output from spatial overlay to CSV file
#Do this for both buffers and drive time
for BufferTable in BufferAppendClasses:
    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(BufferAppendClasses, "BufferAppendTable_{0}".format(BufferTable))

for DriveTimeTable in DriveTimeAppendClasses:
    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(DriveTimeAppendClasses, "DriveTimeAppendTable_{0}".format(DriveTimeTable))

#return Business Analyst and Network Analyst extensions
arcpy.CheckInExtension("Business")
arcpy.CheckInExtension("Network")

print ("DONE")
```

---

I've updated the start of my code to look like the following. I still don't think this is right; I'm getting even more error messages now than I was before.

```
#import arcpy and arcview library; overwrite any previous output
import arcpy
import arcview
import arcgisscripting
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#set workspace to GetParameter field
myWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = myWorkspace
print arcpy.env.workspace

#acquire extensions for Business Analyst and Network Analyst for use
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Business")
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")

#in order to use its tools, add Business Analyst toolbox to script
arcpy.AddToolbox("C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\Business Analyst\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Business Analyst Tools.tbx")

#create GetParameter for input csv table that has store location and lat/long
inputTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#set variables for lat/long table
location = "Location"
xCoord = "Long"
yCoord = "Lat"
tableOutput = "String"

#set the spatial reference; 4269 is code for GCS_North_American_1983
spatialRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(4269)

arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(inputTable, xCoord, yCoord, tableOutput, spatialRef)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(tableOutput, tableOutput)

#Start geoprocessing script to read table and create individual attributes
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.OverWriteOutput = 1

#Set input/output variable for gp
inputFile = tableOutput
outDirectory = myWorkspace

#Read XY layer for different values
rows = gp.searchcursor(inputFile)
row = rows.next()
attributeTypes = set([])

while row:
    attributeTypes.add(row.SiteLocation)
    row = rows.next()

for eachAttribute in attributeTypes:
    outSHP = outDirectory + eachAttribute + u".shp"
    print outSHP
    gp.Select_analysis (inputFile, outSHP, "\"SiteLocation\" = '" + eachAttribute + "'")

del rows, row, attributeTypes, gp
```

Comment: Your code should fail when you try to iterate tables to rows without a cursor or a text file reader.   Just use MakeXYEventLayer once with the entire inputTable, do not try to access each row.  Then if you can use a cursor on that feature class to export each feature or use FeatureClassToFeatureClass to make it into a real point Feature Class first and use a cursor to iterate over that.  You need to give each feature class a unique name, which is not happening in your code (all your layers are named "Location_Location")

Comment: How would I give each location a unique name based on its name under the "location" header in the CSV file?

Comment: I'm also a bit confused on what the proper Cursor function/process to use is? Sorry, I'm a bit inexperienced with using cursors, and the process still confuses me.

Comment: for creating each feature as its own feature class based on an attribute see this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/exporting-feature-class-into-multiple-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-usin

Comment: before your for loops you need to add a line that creates a searchcursor.  See http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm  I.e., with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcBuffer, ["Location"]) as cursor:  arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(fcBuffer, "Buffer_{0}".format(cursor[0]), [0.5, 1, 3], "Miles")

Comment: The feature class post appears to mostly be referencing the split tool, which only applies.to polygons. I'm trying to break down a layer of point features. Unless I'm mistaken...

Comment: Wrong link,  Look at this one.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/exporting-feature-class-into-multiple-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-usin

Comment: @arowl24 - if you're getting more errors, please include them in your question

Comment: The line `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(tableOutput, tableOutput)` will definitely return an error, your input and output can't be the same.

Comment: At the moment I think you are presenting too much code. To try and present just a code snippet I suggest running what you have, see where it throws the first error and then only show us the code up to there and the precise error message. Pretty much the rest of the question can then be edited out. It may be best to start a new question for this so as not to strand the one answer received.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement should be:
`arcpy.MultipleRingBuffer_analysis(fcBuffer, "Buffer_{0}".format(fcBuffer), [0.5, 1, 3], "Miles")`

That will provide the name of each existing featureclass as the input for the tool. It looks like you're making the same mistake in the rest of the subsequent `for` loops also.

Comment: The error occurs before this code, since featureClasses is not a list, it is None, and fcBuffer is never populated.  The mistake is that there are no feature classes created for the ListFeatureClasses to return, since MakeXYEventLayer does not create feature classes, only layers from the CVS file.  Once that is fixed your suggested change would also be necessary to make the rest of the code work.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst My answer focused on resolving the specific error that was occurring. But after looking at the code as a whole I agree that the overall logic for the process needs to be re-thought.