# How to separate shapefile by attributes into a bunch of new shapefiles?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, split-by-attribute

I am trying to work with census block data at the moment, and I want each of the 4178 blocks making the entire state to be their own shapefiles. How can I do this without having to manually query or iterate through each feature and turn each census block into a shapefile with the "Extract Data" function?

Comment: solution? : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/exporting-feature-class-into-multiple-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-usin