# Iterating/looping through Select by Attributes and Export Data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.5, iteration

In ArcMap 10.5.1, I have **2** feature classes in ModelBuilder; both have a common attribute "Well_Nu."

The goal is to loop for each record in the first classes's attribute table and do:

> 1) Select by Attributes - Well_Nu = *each value* 
>   2) Export Data - Export: Selected features, with output feature class: *each value*_1mi.shp

And repeat this same process for the second feature class.

So I need to create individual feature classes for each (selected) feature.

How should this be done in ModelBuilder?

Noting that I would like to do it for the 2 feature classes, though it appears ModelBuilder only supports one iterator in a model; in this case, I could resort to creating 2 models.

Comment: You don't need Modelbuilder for this, see this question: [Exporting feature class into multiple feature classes based on field values using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/exporting-feature-class-into-multiple-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-usin)

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a new feature class you need to add the [Copy Features Tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-features.htm) and set the output feature class accordingly. Your selected data can be the input.

Also, explore using [inline model variable substitution](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/examples-of-inline-model-variable-substitution.htm) to get the naming of the output feature classes.

You will want to use a nested model design with [parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-model-parameter.htm) for multiple iterators.

Comment: Thanks Brad. That helped, though the nested models are presenting a new problem which is beyond the scope of this question and I'll ask another one.