# How to extract data points based on date attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, date, extract

I have around 1.5 million data points of fire incidents during a period of 10 years. I want to extract each month into a new layer so then I will basically have 120 layers in total.

Is there a way to do this without doing it manually one by one i.e. selecting points of every month and extracting it 120 times?

EDIT:
Software: ArcGIS 10.4.1
Data: shapefile

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 10.4.1.

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/278164/edit) the question to give details of the software, and the data, for example in what format is your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a text field called month, calculate following:

[How To: Extract a portion of the Date field](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014933)

but as month instead of minute.

Then see this question: [Exporting feature class into multiple feature classes based on field values using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/exporting-feature-class-into-multiple-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-usin)

second answer, and build a model (since you dont have tool Split By Attributes in 10.4)