# Looping select by Attribute height interval and exporting to individual shapefiles using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, classification, split-by-attribute

I have had a look at the existing Q&As but none of them seem to be addressing this in detail.

I have a building footprint shapefile which contains a height field. I would like to group buildings according to height and store them in separate layers. 
For example I would like to iterate a Select By Attribute SQL query that selects any building between 6 and 9 metres or any building <3 metres. There is thousands of building so doing it by hand is rather unpractical.

I don't mind whether ModelBuilder or Python is used to achieve the result but I am quite new to Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this I would create a simple Model Tool in ModelBuilder that

1. Adds a text field (perhaps named CLASS)
2. Uses a Calculate Field tool that calculates CLASS based on HEIGHT (if that is the name of your height field) with the Python Parser

---

```
def calculate(height):
  if height < 3:
    return "A"
  elif 6 < height < 0.645051:
    return "B"
  else:
    return "X"
```

> CLASS = calculate(!HEIGHT!)

3. Uses Split By Attribute based on field CLASS to create feature classes named A, B, and X.  If your version does not have that tool then there are workarounds in [Exporting feature class into multiple feature classes based on field values using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/exporting-feature-class-into-multiple-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-usin)