# Extracting polygon features based on single layer attribute polygons using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, polygon, arcgis-pro, point, extract

I have a single-point shapefile with gauging locations all around the world, and I also have a shapefile with country boundaries.

See picture of files.

[image: files]

How can I extract the point files that are located within each country and return point feature files based on countries?

I tried to do this manually by just selecting the points and exporting the data to a new file, but was looking to find a way to automate the task instead of doing it manually.

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps:

1. Create a `Spatial Join`. `Target Features`: points - `Join Features`: polygons - `Join Operation`: Join one to many - `Match Option`: Within.
   [image]
2. Use the `Split by attribute` [geoprocessing tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9998/exporting-feature-class-into-multiple-feature-classes-based-on-field-values-usin) on the newly created feature class.
   [image]
3. Result
   [image]